# How to avoid HTML conversion of data retrieved from MySQL

Tags: mysql, html, perl

I am storing data in MySQL like this-

```
5 fruits names are - 
Mango
Orange
Apple
Banana
Grapes
```

I am able to store data in a new line in MySQL. But while fetching it back (using select query)
it's displaying back in a single line in HTML form.

How to avoid that?

Comment: See **[nl2br()](http://it.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php)**.

Comment: @deveshagrawal why are you storing together??? your design is not right them...

Comment: I am using perl to fetch the data from mysql, and passing it to HTML template file.

Comment: @jcho360 Actually this is my requirement. Data can be of any form. single word, single line, multiple line etc... U can compare it like we are asking questions in stackoverflow. So it will be in single column. Right?

Answer (score 3):

Use this in Perl, it is the same as [nl2br](http://php.net/nl2br).

```
sub nl2br {
  my $t = shift or return;
  $t =~ s{([\r\n])}{<br />$1}g;
  return $t;
}
```

Comment: Illegal division by zero.  Check your regex delimiters.

Answer (score 1):

HTML doesn't honor line breaks characters. Use [`nl2br()`](http://php.net/nl2br) to convert the plaintext into HTML markup which WILL have "linebreaks" in it.

Comment: Check my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10899494/810610) for the perl function that works similar to nl2br() php

Comment: Note: question was tagged with [tag:perl], not [tag:php].

Answer (score 1):

If I were you I will stored it with a coma and when you display make a replace, like this:

```
mysql> create table fruits (fruit varchar(200));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.04 sec)

mysql> insert into fruits values ('banana, apple, orange, grapes');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.03 sec)

mysql> select * from fruits;
+-------------------------------+
| fruit                         |
+-------------------------------+
| banana, apple, orange, grapes |
+-------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select replace(fruit,',','<br />') from fruits;
+----------------------------------------------+
| replace(fruit,',','<br />')                  |
+----------------------------------------------+
| banana<br /> apple<br /> orange<br /> grapes |
+----------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

and you are not tied to display the listing how you want to, just change the 
 tag for any tag that you want

or if you want a listing, you can use this

```
mysql> select concat('<ol><li>',replace(fruit,',','</li><li>'),'</li></ol>') from fruits;
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| concat('<ol><li>',replace(fruit,',','</li><li>'),'</li></ol>')          |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| <ol><li>banana</li><li> apple</li><li> orange</li><li> grapes</li></ol> |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, just replace all `\n` with `<br />`.

Answer (score 0):

Since I dont have any idea about your code, my best guess is that you are not using any formatting. 
If you are using php or scriptlets to retrieve your data, you can get all your data into may be an array and print 
that array over a loop with html format. 
You could also make use of AJAX and print it out the way you want to appear in HTML. 
It would be helpful if you post some code.